# JOIN SQL not working as it should be

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, join

I have tabel for courses(CID,CName) and another table shows majors for each course CourseMajor(CID,MNom).

I have a drop dawn list which has majors numbers. if the user select a major number from the list another list should be filled of courses that are from the selected major.

I have the code below show me all courses not only the courses for the selected major number !
I used LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, INNER JOIN, FULL OUTER JOIN....and none of them work.

note: I am using C#, asp.net, vs.net...

```
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TBCourse FULL JOIN TbCourseMajor ON  TBCourse.CId = TbCourseMajor.CId  AND TbCourseMajor.MNom = '" + DLMNom.SelectedValue + "' ", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    reader.Read();


                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                     DLCName.Items.Add(new ListItem(reader["CName"].ToString(), reader["CNom"].ToString()));

                    }
                }
                else { TxtCRN.Text = "Not worked"; }
            }
        }
```

This is some details about tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBCourse] (
    [CId]    INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [CNom]   INT           NOT NULL,
    [CName]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Chours] NCHAR (10)    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TBCourse] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CId] ASC)
);


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TbCourseMajor] (
    [CId]  INT NOT NULL,
    [MNom] INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CId] ASC),
    FOREIGN KEY ([CId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TBCourse] ([CId]),
    FOREIGN KEY ([MNom]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TbMajor] ([MNom])
);
```

Comment: If you only want to see courses from the selected major number, you would use an `INNER JOIN`.  If that's not working, you'll need to tell us more about your database schema (how `TBCourse` relates to `TbCourseMajor`), provide some sample data, and tell us what you're getting when you select a particular major number.

Comment: Yep. Every time user changes major, you have to re-query SQL to get list of courses for that major. However, I believe there has to be a reference table between them because one course can be included in more than one major.

Comment: devlin carnage Thank u for replay. INNER JOIN  gives 0 rows after execute I will write details about tables above.

Comment: Thanks Slava Murygin for replaying .. In my database one course belong to one major only.  the problem not because of updating it is about wrong result of SQL command.

Comment: First, take MS SQL Management Studio and run your query in plaintext.
Second - don't use "ON" Clause for "WHERE" (this works, but is sortof misuse)
And third - go and shame yourself for concatenating an SQL-query for no reason. Use SQLParameters!

Comment: Thanks all for replaying. The problem was as  devlin carnage said in database (in stored data) ,  the second table has a problem (not store data) it shows null.. I created another table with the same data and it works perfectly.. Thanks all and sorry for not being able to identify the problem from the beginning. Thanks again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was as  devlin carnage said in database (in stored data) ,  the second table has a problem (not store data) it shows null.. I created another table with the same data and it works perfectly.. Thanks all and sorry for not being able to identify the problem from the beginning.